# 'ElementRef' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, typescript

i was trying to access my element this way:

```
@ViewChild('addNodeDefinition' , {read: ElementRef}) editNodeModal: ElementRef;
```

but i get error:

> 'ElementRef' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

my html:

```
<ng-template #addNodeDefinition></ng-template>
```

what's the problem? thanks

Comment: The post here should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template#answer-35209681 It's possible you need to chang `{read: ElementRef}` to `{read: ViewContainerRef}`

Comment: @peinearydevelopment thanks but my problem is i didn't use ```ElementRef``` as a value but i got this error.

Comment: You are using it as a value though. `{read: ElementRef}`. That is a JavaScript object, `read` is the property name and `ElementRef` is the value you are assigning to that property.